# Crear una capa semi-traslúcida de background en un view

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Necesito hacer un *background* semi-traslúcido en una vista. Para ello hago uso de `UIVisualEffectView`.

Creo un `UIView` transparente a modo de contenedor y dentro otro *view* al que le pongo el efecto traslúcido. Pero al añadirlo me varía la altura (height) de la vista padre. Es decir aparece con más altura.

¿Cómo debo hacer para tener una vista con fondo traslúcido?

Lo que tengo ahora es lo siguiente:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = self.viewTranslucent.bounds;
[self.viewTranslucent insertSubview:visualEffectView atIndex:0];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a mi me funciono cambiarlo así

```
visualEffectView.frame = self.view.frame; //self.viewTranslucent.bounds;
```

estoy usando un uiviewcontroller

Comment: De esta manera a mi me lo añade debajo del self.view y con un margen entre self.view y el background traslucido

Comment: Alfinal lo resolvi añadiendo "constraints" a la vista con el efecto visual.